# Asp.Net Treeview/ Sub Category

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I am building a fitness application using asp.net mvc. The code I have displayed on here shows everything being as a list group item. This is not what I want. I want the user to be able to click "programs" and then what is in the list groups currently, to drop down and be like a sub-category. Every drop down code I have tried hasn't worked yet. Any assistance would be greatly appreciated!

```
 <div class="sidebar-heading bg-success font-weight-bold " style="color:white;">Programs</div>
            <a class="list-group-item list-group-item-action bg-dark font-weight-bold font-italic" style="color:white;" asp-area="" asp-controller="Programs" asp-action="Indoor/ Home Workouts">Home/Indoor Workouts</a>
            <a class="list-group-item list-group-item-action bg-dark font-weight-bold font-italic" style="color:white;" asp-area="" asp-controller="Programs" asp-action="Gym">Gym Workouts</a>
            <a class="list-group-item list-group-item-action bg-dark font-weight-bold font-italic" style="color:white;" asp-area="" asp-controller="Programs" asp-action="Running">Crossfit Workouts</a>
            <a class="list-group-item list-group-item-action bg-dark font-weight-bold font-italic" style="color:white;" asp-area="" asp-controller="Programs" asp-action="Running">Running Training</a>
            <a class="list-group-item list-group-item-action bg-dark font-weight-bold font-italic" style="color:white;" asp-area="" asp-controller="Programs" asp-action="Military">Military Workouts</a>
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33415410/categories-subcategories-in-asp-net-mvc Hope this helps with your requirement?

Comment: What have you tried so far? Show us your backend side code as well and explain where you stuck.